# Opacity value displayed as string instead of number

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, opacity

I have a simple opacity slider using react hooks which looks like this

[image]

I am setting opacity in a table like this

```
<td>
<img
   src="link"
   opacity={data.socialOpacity}
   }
   />
</td>
```

But when I run my app the opacity in DOM shows as a string like this

```
<img src="https://wp-iframe.icon.webp" color="#000" opacity="1">
```

Why the opacity value displays as a string and not a number?

Comment: There are no numeric attribute values.

Comment: HTML is a different and mostly completely distinct "language" from JavaScript. Attribute values are always text, or "strings" as one would say in the context of JavaScript or other languages.

Comment: That looks like HTML rather than DOM (the former is often used to generate the latter). HTML does not have types, it isn't a programming language.

Comment: Also `<img>` elements don't accept an "opacity" attribute anyway.

Comment: There may be some confusion between opacity as attempted to be used here which would apply to SVG elements but not HTML ones - see [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/opacity and CSS opacity as applied to an HTML img element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some notes:

- we don't have `opacity` property in html.
- we don't have `color` property in html too and css `color` propery doesn't affect on images.
- you should use state management in react and `setState()`function.
- or use this simple code with `style` property:

`<div style={ {opacity: data.socialOpacity, color: "#111"} } >...</div>`